# Webrtc for only watching?

Tags: webrtc

Is it possible for two customers(users) to have a videochat, so the others only can watch them? Something  similar to Deeyoon.com. Deeyoon don't use webrtc.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle this logic by your own.

You can create the peer connection between the speakers. And, also send both these two streams to server.

For all other users, you can just pass these streams. (In this part, you don't need to create a peerview connection)